# vue axios Uncaught (in promise) Cancel

Tags: exception, try-catch, axios

I see an error message saying "Uncaught (in promise) Cancel" even though the I used catch function to handle exceptions. My code looks like this:

```
this.http.get(params, { cancelToken }).catch(...)
```

I have the `catch` part, why do I still see the error?

Answer (score 1):

axios's `cancelToken` is deprecated. Try using `AbortController`: https://axios-http.com/docs/cancellation