# Vue Axios Uncaught (in promise) GET Request Error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, endpoint

```
axios.get('localhost:3000/api/event')
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
    });
```

The above code is being used in one of my Vue files and is retrieving data from a server I have set up and successfully tested endpoints with in Postman. The server is currently running, and I am trying to do a get request (from a separate file folder-my client) from the database. When I try this, I get "Uncaught (in promise) AxiosError \ code: ERR_BAD_REQUEST" in my console.

I have looked through other similar questions: [vue axios Uncaught (in promise) Cancel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57217514/vue-axios-uncaught-in-promise-cancel) , [Vue axios error Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 415](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69337803/vue-axios-error-uncaught-in-promise-error-request-failed-with-status-code-415) , and others but found either an unsatisfactory answer or no answer at all.

My endpoint is correct, the server is running (I can query that same endpoint with Postman and get the JSONs I desire), and I *believe* my syntax is correct for the axios code. I would love some help with this please.

Comment: `bad request` tells you that the server dont accept the request. look at the browser network dev tools to get maybe more informatoin

Comment: also, the process for importing axios was : "npm install axios" in the root folder and then adding "import axios from 'axios';" in my vue file. @Sysix , I checked that and it pointed me to an if statement section that writes: 

"if (protocol && platform.protocols.indexOf(protocol) === -1) {
      reject(new AxiosError('Unsupported protocol ' + protocol + ':', AxiosError.ERR_BAD_REQUEST, config));
      return;
    }
"

I'm not entirely sure what to make of this outside of the fact that it is simply another way to say "there is an error"

Comment: unsupported protocol means, that u missing `https` or `http` at the beginning of your url.

Comment: Try this, `http://localhost:3000/api/event`

Comment: You are both right, I forgot to include the http:// at the beginning of my syntax, and am now coming across a CORS related error. I am looking across the documentation for CORS and other related questions. I keep finding talk of adding the domain in the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header but am not sure what file that belongs in. I will keep looking for a solution, but it would save me some time if anyone here knows. Thank you.